# Uploading a significantly large number of files using Windows Server 2019 FTP service

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2019

I have configured the FTP service in a Windows Server 2019 where I need to upload a large number (around 2 million) of documents/files (PDFs, XMLs, etc.). I started the upload process with only a few files but, at some point, this process always fails. Specifically, the FTP connection drops and the Internet service in my PC also fails. Firstly, I used FileZilla and then I changed to WinSCP without success. My last test was as follows:

1 block of 5 folders with 12,482 files in total and around 700 MB.
1 block of 6 folders with 3,158 files in total and around 200 MB.
The process to upload the files is:

I open the FTP connection providing my administrator credentials
I select the first block of 5 folders and drag and drop to the FTP location.
I select the second block of 6 folders and drag and drop to the FTP location.
The first block was uploaded successfully but the second was not. I have been performing several tests since last week (at least 15) and all of them fail at some point.

We also have a Lynux server so I configured an FTP here just to see the behavior and all the tests were successful. This suggests to me that the problem has to do with the Windows Server 2019 FTP service.

I was recommended to read and apply the information in this link (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/ftpserver/connections) which I did without results. There was, however, a difference: I could upload more files.

I will very much appreciate your feedback.

Respectfully, Jorge Maldonado

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use windows file sharing?

Comment: Yes. We are moving our web server to the cloud and need to upload everything. We have unlimited amount of data to transfer so this is not a possible issue for our problem

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Auto-Tuning feature may sometimes cause such problems.
Try to disable it in a CMD run as admin:

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

If this fails, zipping the files and uploading the zip archive using an
FTP product that supports resume (in case) should work better,
since it only requires one connection.